# How to pass variables to different Threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I'm making a program that gets live price information from an API. I then want to display the price information on a JavaFX chart that live updates. When I try to pass the information to the JavaFX Thread it doesn't always pass over correctly and the JavaFX thread doesn't get the price information.

The API call is done on a separate thread and when it has the information it then calls the updateScene method. This is where I get an issue, the API Thread has all the information I try and set the variable for the JavaFX thread to use and it has none of the information.

```
private CandleStickFeed candleStickFeed;

public void updateScene(CandleStickFeed candleStickFeed){

    this.candleStickFeed = candleStickFeed;

    System.out.println("Feed Size This Thread = " + candleStickFeed.getSize());

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
        
        @Override
        public void run(){
            
            System.out.println("Feed Size JavaFX Thread = " + candleStickFeed.getSize());
            updateChart();
        }
    });
}
```

The program will sometimes output

> Feed Size This Thread = 5
>
> Feed Size JavaFX Thread = 5

Which is what I would expected. But it also sometimes outputs

> Feed Size This Thread = 5
>
> Feed Size JavaFX Thread = 0

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I new to using multiple threads so not sure what I'm doing really. I have looked for different answers but couldn't find any. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to extract the relevant information from the `candleStickFeed`, and pass that structure into a Runnable subclass.

```
public void updateScene(CandleStickFeed candleStickFeed) {
    CandleStickData data = new CandleStickData(candleStickFeed);
    Platform.runLater(new ChartUpdateRunnable (data));
}

private class CandleStickData {
    private double[] numbers; // or whatever you need
    CandleStickData (CandleStickFeed candleStickFeed) {
        this.numbers = new double[candleStickFeed.getSize()];
        // TODO: populate the data structure
    }
}

private ChartUpdateRunnable implements Runnable {
    private CandleStickData data;
    ChartUpdateRunnable(CandleStickData data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Feed Size JavaFX Thread = " + data);
        updateChart();
    }
}
```

The principle is to not pass around a feed class which might change state often, but extract an immutable state object, and pass that to a runnable class instance for update.

Comment: Thank you, this has helped a lot and got my program working

Answer (score 4):

This is a supplement to @Simon's answer.

Your problem is not about "passing a variable." Your `runLater(...)` task apparently is getting the value of the variable. The problem is that the value is a *reference* to a *mutable object,* and that object sometimes is modified in between the time when the task is created and the time when the task is executed.

Simon's suggestion boils down to this: Give the new task its own private copy of whatever information it will need from the `CandleStickFeed` instance, and let it work exclusively from that private copy.

Comment: Thank you for the additional explanations very helpful